# Can a graph be colored such that adjacent vertices are different colors and non-adjacent vertices are the same color?

Tags: algorithm, graph-coloring

Given a graph, is there an efficient algorithm to color its vertices such that any two adjacent vertices are different colors, and any two non-adjacent vertices are the same color, and to do so with the minimum number of colors?

What I have realized is that, except for the trivial case where the graph has no edges, it must be connected, otherwise such a coloring is impossible: take any existing edge u-v, and it's clear that any other vertex x must be joined to one of its endpoints, otherwise color(x) = u and color(x) = v, contradicting color(u) != color(v).

Any other ideas for how to solve this problem?

Comment: This looks like a graph theory problem, not a coding problem

Comment: It’s an algorithm question. Where do you suggest I post it then?

Comment: This is easier if you consider the graph with the complement of the edge set, i.e. vertices are adjacent when they are not in the original graph and vice-versa.

Comment: @cupcake111680 I think any of these would be better https://math.stackexchange.com/ or https://mathoverflow.net/ or https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ or https://scicomp.stackexchange.com
I'm not as active on those, so you should explore which of them would be the best option I think.

Comment: @Henry How does that help exactly?

Comment: http://mrsleblancsmath.pbworks.com/w/file/fetch/46119304/vertex%20coloring%20algorithm.pdf check this.

Comment: This is a NP complete problem [Chrommatic number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChromaticNumber.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider the graph with the complement of the edge set, i.e. vertices are adjacent when they are not in the original graph and vice-versa.

In this new graph vertices that are adjacent must have the same color. This means, all vertices forming a connected component must have the same color. Further, if a coloring is possible, this connected component must be a complete graph (i.e. all vertices are pairwise adjacent) because otherwise there are two nodes in the component that are connected in the original gaph and must therefore have different color: a contradiction.

Now, each connected component in the new graph must have a different color.